# Black ink cartridges MP620 how to use both of them

Tags: ink

Also regarding Canon printer MP-620. It has two black cartridges. A large #220 and a smaller #221 black cartridge. It NEVER uses the smaller black cartridge even when the larger one runs out of ink and gives all the warning messages. How can one switch to the smaller?Otherwise, what use is it?

Answer (score 0):

Dan Richard explains that in

[How to use the other black ink cartridge when one is empty on your Canon Pixma MX850 Printer!](http://www.danrichard.com/2011/07/14/how-to-use-the-other-black-ink-cartidge-when-one-is-empty-on-your-canon-pixma-mx850-printer/)

> 1. Click on print to get the print options window in whatever program you’re using… This is the window where you normally select the printer you want to use, how many copies etc.
> 2. Within that window, you should see a link, button or icon that allows you to adjust the printer settings, such as paper, paper source, ink use etc.
> 3. Switch the paper type from regular paper to “high resolution paper”.